# Best linear predictors given ACF and Mean

Tags: time-series, mathematical-statistics, predictive-models, autocorrelation

I am working on the following problem and cannot seem to arrive at the correct solution:

Let X1, X2, … be a stationary time series with mean μ=5 and ACF p(h)=(0.9)^|h|. Demonstrate that the best linear predictor for Xn+2 of the type aXn+b is a = 0.81 and b = 0.95

From my reading I understand that we use a MSE approach to find the appropriate a and b. Now if we had some data it would be straightforward to run a MSE and find them, but how would one express this solution in a purely analytical manner?

Any resources or hints would be appreciated! :)

Comment: Could you explain, quantitatively, what "best" means?  That would be a good starting point because it should give you enough information (in the form of *two* equations) to solve for $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Quantitatively "best" would mean the coefficients a and b which given the series X1, X2, ... minimize the difference between Xn+2 and Xn+2 "hat". Now in the examples I've found a is treated as a series i.e. (a0, a1 ...) with each X in the series having it's own a coefficient, yet in this problem we are given single values for a and b. I can only assume that the requirement is to predict Xn+2 based only on Xn. This would explain a=0.81 since the ACF is p(h)=(0.9)^|h| (h=2->p(h)=0.81). Yet how do we use the information that μ=5 and b=0.95?

Comment: You cannot hope to minimize the difference.  First, you certainly mean the *size* of the difference.  Despite that, you can't minimize it because it's random.  Therefore all you can hope to do is minimize certain properties of this random variable.  The properties usually considered most important are (a) to be correct on average and (b) to have little chance of deviating too much from the average.

Comment: So we are minimizing (a) The expected value of the size of the difference between Xn+2 and Xn+2"hat" and (b) the variance of Xn+2"hat"

Comment: Because it is rare to be able to optimize two objectives simultaneously, you will have to compromise somehow.  A classic method is to set one of your objectives as a constraint and optimize the other subject to that constraint.  Another (more modern) approach is to optimize some function of the two objectives, such as a positive linear combination of the two, and to use other methods (like cross validation) to find the right function.  But since this is a theoretical question, rather than one about data, you probably have to pick the first approach.

Comment: That was very useful thank you so much! I think I will be able to do it now :)